# Spring scheduler cron expression not working

Tags: java, spring-scheduled

We are use spring scheduler with following setting but wondering why its not working for us?

Our expectation is it should execute every day at 2 AM, Is anything wrong with that?

```
<task:scheduled ref="invoiceScheduler" method="updateInvoiceStatusToOverDue" cron="0 0 2 * * ?" />
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try adding some more information.

Comment: invoiceScheduler is our bean which have method/function updateInvoiceStatusToOverDue(){...} we want to invoke/execute this function everyday at 2 AM. Spring scheduler is not invoking updateInvoiceStatusToOverDue method that is the problem.

Comment: Did you add @EnableScheduling in the config class?

Comment: Scheduling with fixed-rate is working for e.g. <task:scheduled ref="orderCreateScheduler" method="createOrder" fixed-rate="10000"/>

Comment: also tried with "0 0 2 * * *" (removed ?) but no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

This cron works for my SpringBoot application:
`@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 2 1/1 * *")`

Btw, what "doesn't work"? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: is this a comment or an answer?

Comment: You should add this as a comment.

Comment: would love to, but I need 50 rep to do so. And this is the answer hopefully

Comment: The question is incomplete, so is your answer actually.

Comment: invoiceScheduler is our bean which have method/function updateInvoiceStatusToOverDue(){...} we want to invoke/execute this function everyday at 2 AM. Spring scheduler is not invoking updateInvoiceStatusToOverDue method that is the problem.

Comment: @Peter777 reference from spring doc https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html 
"0 0 6,19 * * *" = 6:00 AM and 7:00 PM every day. I changed it to "0 0 2 * * *" This expression should also work Can you please let me know purpose of 1/1.

Comment: @AmitJain  `"1/1"` in my cron expression basically means every day starting from 1st day of the month

Comment: I want to execute method every day at 2 AM only one time in a day.

Comment: @AmitJain please read carefully - this is 2 am every day starting from 1st day of the month

Answer (score 0):

The following task is being scheduled to run 10 minutes past each hour but only during the 8-to-5 "business hours" on weekdays.

`scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("0 10 8-17 * * MON-FRI"));`

Could you please try this:

`scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("0 1 2 * * MON-FRI"));`

**OR**

`scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("0 1 2 * * *"));`

Answer (score 0):

"0 0 2 * * *" instead of  "0 0 2 * * ?" helped us to achieve scheduler to invoke every day at 2 AM. Thanks everyone for finding time and helping me.